# Add Custom Data Table In Dwg Model File

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

We have a dwg file [input model dwg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWOb0.png) that has model added inside page boundry. We want to add to table to this dwg file and position it inside page boundry. And later export this file as dwg [Expected output dwg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmOyl.png)

How it can be achieved using Autodesk Design Automation API or Autodesk Forge Viewer or any other way possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Table dwg as a main template and insert your model into, I answered here which is similar to this.
[Create new dwg file and load existing dwg model in it using Autodesk Design Automation API for AutoCAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75381976/create-new-dwg-file-and-load-existing-dwg-model-in-it-using-autodesk-design-auto/75393518#75393518)

Comment: Thanks @Madhukar for answering, but in our use case we want to generate new table ( data, table size ) each time on operation, so we can't keep a static Table dwg template. Could you recommend what can be done for this to generate a new custom table ( given different data and size each time ) on dwg file

Comment: Dynamic creation of Table in AutoCAD drawing is possible, refer https://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/how-to-create-a-table-and-fill-in-its-cells-with-net.html