# Workitem failing on UpdateDwgParamActivity | Autodesk Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

I followed autodesk platform service official tutorial for [Design Automation](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/design-automation/) and clone [github repo](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-design-automation-nodejs) the sample app .
I followed all the instruction to run the app exactly, sample app is running but when i am trying to use "UpdateDwgParamsActivity" workitem is failing.

[Workitem failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81VS3.png)
[Error report url](https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/YR4rlmfrF0a3Z6BRSxcxD5GW652EKPut/91ef28685eca40b48521f6e84e07de6f/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=90000&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjENn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCnuypTjsu3vmVhMuZ6f64%2BmNLJsH0AhaPMLNfPvcehoQIgB9zm1ocm4om5ouVdd989dw7KhZM8QRJkALy8V%2BE%2BtsEqgAMIcRADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDOlvtPGAD0mIm8IaCyrdAuovy6GQO6%2F2JPwm3QLDegJJD0kUEZ3hN3nRVsY7zzjya8cneFZ1wZ94JMBy2EXhulcyqR4zZjymGggEdzgF0T%2B7gmBlVMsc%2BkQnphI0YIq7WFDkPwvpur6DCN0NgY1Otd0FFpOoFjClOihX%2BwppEAwcmZ6HrTY38HyHvJDJDBHskSzled7lDhQEzYvr7D053nR4IeCfe2fTf9eRAv0kweDzxisZHSJ4oUzR4bEi5IHDGDsx3ms0Jok1McVY6iJVcGOo%2BZBWRjtMUUNzap6lTekl%2BK9UERNhKW%2FtyEktmWecc8S9EIRcQysOt5lPPDRmKCO7a0Ta0dcuxoHn7SyfuUkhYfR7Wd%2FTpxImrRIQU%2Bha1E68bPkuNWYkar06Qt0Cgji%2FACR%2B3evW0wVmwtqfMONb51aoVLQQ4L2q%2BIpmkCZZZ3GAkhuNWhkgXlI7m0%2BEgRjxAjxE2Fc3gtYEDsMwm5DCnwY6ngHdOAMtYbw6CdKOC4o9D9hU5vla5bYsA26prHal7zIWzMlW3TfGsYp0EBdq1%2FWsRq81wU%2BOCini0cscQhN4b3IGqBrY0dLUqdWK6Fy4pf%2B%2FziY8D%2FjA3lk4ojWcqhijUb%2F3lWsdKeh4BJzLdMk237l4RHC3jnHcdTpgAOwY2xCHa1O%2BLXBMRB%2B06n6s3QRVjiopsTfTs0FNQ6A2D%2BqAuQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3MJI2ZEEI/20230218/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230218T084111Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=e9c217e4a9c4c281cf9b4b4e177ea812b15444e596e37233f275d00a89b45e5b)

I am not sure what is issue here, i have already tried with "clear account" and then creating app bundle again but it is not working.
Although input and output file is getting uploaded to oss bucket, but output file doesn't have any changes and it's same as input ( width & height didn't change )

Please let me know what is the issue here and how it can be solved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "ActivityId":"YR4rlmfrF0a3Z6BRSxcxD5GW652EKPut.UpdateDWGParamActivity+dev"
> "Engine.Id":"Autodesk.3dsMax_2020!43"

You selected the wrong Engine, for activity `UpdateDwgParamActivity`, you need to select `Autodesk.AutoCAD+24_1`